# How to call Navigation Drawer Menu from another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I know similar questions have been asked before but is there any clear easy to understand example to do this.  What I usually do is create a project from Android Studio and select the one with navigation on it.  But after I call my next activity it does not have the navigation drawer anymore.  All I can do is just add a back button to the main activity in the toolbar.  All I want is to have the ability to call the navigation drawer from all my activitie even those with a back button on the toolbar.

Is there a best practice to make the navigation drawer menu callable  which is applicable to different scenarios.  For example

```
main activity with drawer ->  2nd activity with toolbar but has back button. How do you call the drawer menu?
main activity with drawer ->  3rd activity with no toolbar.  call navigation drawer thru swipe or buttons?
```

Comment: I never knew that being new on a very complicated topic in software development merits a down-vote. Specially android development which has undergone different versions with different version compatibility issues and design transformation.   I don't care about points so down vote as you want but please leave a reason why you down-voted the question to make it a more valuable learning process.  Please note that not all are geniuses that can grasp all this different approaches in design and programming concepts.  All of us has been noobs at one point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can achieve that by having a base activity that you can extend from any activity that you want it to have the DL.  for example

```
public abstract class SampleBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected abstract boolean isHome();

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            if (!isHome()) {
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
            } else {
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

            }
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (isHome()) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                onBackPressed();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

now in every activity you like to have the drawer extend this `activity` instead of the normal `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Sorry for a newbie question but for what I am doing right now whenever I extend the MainActivity to another activity it says NoBoringActionBarActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: then u need to change the AppCompatActivity to whatever activity you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Each Activity has its own actionBar and each actionbar can use own Navigation Drawer. So If You want to same navigation Drawer. You can use Fragment. You can make MainActivity has Navigation Drawer and Use FrameLayout in Mainactivity Then Replace Fragment. if You want each Activity has single Navigation Drawer. it is not Possible.